# Can't re-select radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, radio-button

I have made a little [web quiz](http://boaz.comze.com/Quiz/index/index.html).

The problem is when clicking the back button, I want to re-select the user's last choice and it doesn't seem to work, I have no idea why.

Here is my `go_back` function:

```
function go_back(){
  $("#back").bind("click",function(){
    qNum--;
    if(AnsW.length === 0){
      calcAnswers--;
    }
    tempAns = AnsW[qNum];
    //user's last answer, which is false. I need this to make the radio button point to that answer.
    showQuestion(qNum);
    $("#contain").find("input[value="+tempAns+"]").prop('checked', true);
    AnsW.splice(-1,1);
    //delete the false answer from the array. I need this to make sure that the answer is deleted and there won't be an overload of wrong answers
    if(qNum === 0){
      $("#back").css({"visibility":"hidden"})
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: when you are clicking aback button, you api does not seem to have the previously selected value

Comment: when you go back in the browser, AnsW var remember the previously selected value? I use cookies for this proposal

Comment: my rest of code is at the site its 200+ lines so i dont want to spam this article. and Curlas yes i save my answers in the AnsW array, i dont use cookies , i prefer using localStorage or sessionStorage for those purpose...if the only sulotion is to use cookie then fine but i prefer not doing that, id rather prefer to try first with an array then do it using localstorage.

Comment: well anyone have a slotion?

Answer (score -1):

Use attribute **selected** in the radio button.

```
<input type="radio" selected value="1"/>
```

Incase jQuery try below,

```
$("radio option[value='B']").attr("selected","selected");
```